# Installing Selenium Automation 2.53.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, maximo

My question is based on [this document](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=2a504236-951e-4737-949b-660cfa1c895e&ps=25).

I've installed all of the necessary jars and executables like it says in the document for the installation.   I've also setup the eclipse environment and installed TestNG.   I've made an Apache Http Server as well, basically I did everything as it says in the installation document.

But now I need to move the files "Inspector.js" and "TpaeInspector.js" to a central location and then change the location, where it was copied, of the Inspector.js on line 32 in TpaeInspector.js.

This is the current line 32:

```
https://PathToFileServer/Inspector.js"]
```

And I've moved the files to a map I've created on my desktop (C:\Users\anabe\Desktop\Test Selenium), so it should look like this:
C:\Users\anabe\Desktop\Test Selenium\Inspector.js"]

And lastly I need to make a bookmark in my browser and edit it to this line:

```
javascript: 
void(require(["https://<InspectorLocation>/TpaeInspector.js"], 
function(inspector){new inspector().startup(/*headless*/false, 
"https://<InspectorLocation>/TpaeInspector.js")}));
```

Where the `<InspectorLocation>` is the current location of the Inspector file, so it should look like this:

```
javascript: void(require(["C:\Users\anabe\Desktop\Test 
Selenium\TpaeInspector.js"], function(inspector){new 
inspector().startup(/*headless*/false, "C:\Users\anabe\Desktop\Test 
Selenium\TpaeInspector.js")}));
```

It still doesn't work, can anyone tell me what I did wrong?